# can't bind href with php function

Tags: php

I'm working on a new website. This website will be a one pager. All my files I already load in through PHP into the main folder. But now I want to edit them and update them through WYSIWYG.

The UPDATE and SELECT are already working. I tested it on a page who stood on its own. All the one-pager files are stored in a folder and within the folder is also the file which loads all the files into it. I call them through a href which ends up giving the file an # in the address bar. There lies the problem. I can't access the **#file** with the function I wrote because that only can access files without starting a #. Is it possible to access it through my function?

I give the code if the question is too unclear because it's a bit of mess to implement all the files I use for this purpose.

**Short recap:** Can't access #domain with a PHP function. Is it even possible to access it.

```
<?php

    class Home extends Controller {

        protected function frontpage() {

            $viewmodel = new HomeModel();
            $this->returnView($viewmodel->frontpage(), true);
        }
    }

?>
```

this is the returnView from Controller:

```
protected function returnView($viewmodel, $fullview){
    $view = 'views/'. get_class($this). '/' . $this->action. '.php';
    if($fullview){
        require('views/main.php');
    } else {
        require($view);
    }
}
```

I'm new with overflow so I couldn't get the function into right place but with protected function frontpage I should access the file frontpage.php. Well it does do that but that's not the right directory because it's only visible throug a href which means the function should have been: **protected function #frontpage** which isn't possible.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, it will be helpful to understand what you really want

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible, as the anchor (`#`) isn't sent to the server and is handled by the browser itself.

The only possibility is to include some JavaScript magic to your project.

Comment: Do you also have some examples? I found an example with almost the same question only the direction it was heading was way different than mine. I can't find anything else so far.